# C++: scope of for loop?

Tags: c++, loops, scope

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i <= 11; i+=3)
        cout << i;
    cout << endl << i << endl;
}
```

output is: 0 3 6 and 9 and then once it exits the loop its 12.
The addresses of i inside the loop and out appear the same

What I need to know is: Is the i inside the for loop the same as the i that was initialized outside the for loop because the variable i was first initialized before the for loops i was ever created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's de same 'i' var

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int i = 0;

int main() {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i <= 11; i+=3)
        cout << i;
    cout << endl << i << endl;
    cout << endl << ::i << endl;
}
```

i is 12

::i is 0

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the i inside the loop is the same as the i outside of the loop because you've only declared it once.

If for some reason you want it to be different (which I highly recommend against, you should choose different names for different variables) you could redeclare the i in the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a new object (variable) in C++ (as well as in C) you have to explicitly *define* it. In your program you have one and only one variable definition - `int i;`. That immediately means that there's one and only one variable `i` there. There's no chance for any other `i`, regardless of any "scopes of for loop" or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one 'i' variable. You're just assigning a value in the foor loop.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one variable extant here - and yes, the i inside the loop is the same as the one you output after exiting the loop.  However the variable was only initialized as part of the loop, not before.

Answer (score 0):

A `for-loop` of the form:

```
for (init condition; expression) statement
```

Is exactly equivalent to:

```
{
    init
    while (condition)
    {
        statement
        expression;
    }
}
```

So with your code:

```
    int i;
    {
        i=0;
        while (i <= 11)
        {
            cout << i;
            i += 3;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << i << endl;
}
```

Can you tell now? [Andrey puts it best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640337/c-scope-of-for-loop/3640465#3640465): if you didn't define it, it doesn't exist.